# neo4j parallel traversal api

Tags: parallel-processing, neo4j, graph-traversal

The answer to this post ([find distinct paths in neo4j database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21218397/find-distinct-paths-in-neo4j-database/21223247#21223247)) recommends using the Traversal API to identify distinct paths in a graph (please see original question) instead of a Cypher query. For a graph containing 10,000 nodes the API returned the results immediately; much faster than the Cypher query.

I would like to create the same results for a graph containing more than 100 mio. nodes. Based on a simple progress check I added to the code, identifying the distinct paths might well take several hours. The database files are in total ca. 500 MB. Memory does not seem to be a problem, but CPU is running at 12% (on an 8-core machine) => it looks like the process is CPU-constrained. Is there any way to make the process run in parallel?

I am using Neo4j 2.1.3, JRE 1.7.0_51-b13 (64-Bit), runnning on Windows 8.

Many thanks!

Comment: I did some poking around trying to find some info for a reasonable response. I found this worth checking out:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18881351/adding-relationships-to-a-neo4j-database-in-parallel   It's not really an answer, but the beginnings of one.  Generic advice might be to write your own traversal, divide it into multiple java threads and so on - but more specific advice on how to do any kind of parallel computation over a neo4j database would be a good thing.

Comment: Thanks Frobber: I will take a look and post an update if I discover anything. Let's see if we get any other replies too.